# JList items come back after deletion?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am creating a JList with a JTextField and 2 JButtons (Add/Delete). Once I hit the delete button it deletes but comes back once I input another item into the List. I do not know if I messed up, but here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class i extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField jTextField;
private DefaultListModel ListModel = new DefaultListModel();
private ArrayList<String> ListArray = new ArrayList <String>();
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                i frame = new i();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public i() {


    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    jTextField = new JTextField();
    jTextField.setBounds(15, 80, 168, 20);
    contentPane.add(jTextField);
    jTextField.setColumns(10);

    JButton jButton = new JButton("Add");
    jButton.setBounds(193, 79, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(jButton);
    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!jTextField.getText().equals("")){
                ListModel.clear();
                ListArray.add(jTextField.getText());
                jTextField.setText("");
                for (int i=0; i<ListArray.size(); i++){
                    ListModel.add(i, ListArray.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    final JList jList = new JList(ListModel);
    jList.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    jList.setBounds(289, 11, 135, 240);
    contentPane.add(jList);

    JButton delete = new JButton("DELETE");
    delete.setBounds(193, 161, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(delete);
    delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent k){
            ListModel.removeElement(jList.getSelectedValue());
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are removing the element from the `JList`, but you are not removing it from your array. Your add button repopulates the `JList` from the array and so all the items are re-added.

You'll have to remove it from the data array.

One way to keep it tidy is to make a single method that clears the list then repopulates it from the array. Then you can just make all modifications to the array and call that method to update the list without duplicating that logic everywhere.

[Silly Freak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22259080/616460) and splungebob also bring up a good point; you *could* store all the items in the `DefaultListModel` and drop the array entirely. In a more complex application, you might implement your own `ListModel` that reflects whatever data structure you are storing your objects in. For your application, just using a `DefaultListModel` as a storage container would be fine, though, and would simplify your code a bit (and would automatically update the `JList` without you having to clear and repopulate).

By the way, traditional Java naming convention is to start variable names with lowercase letters. Other programmers may have a tough time reading your code because capitalized names are generally reserved for class names (you can see even SO's syntax highlighter gets a bit confused).

Comment: +1 I'm not even sure why the ListArray is even needed.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @engz I could tell you, but the [`ArrayList` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) can tell you better.

Comment: I am sorry, but I'm having trouble with this. I took out the ListArray and now am trying to currently add the input from the JTextField, but I am stuck.

Comment: @engz Stuck where? Check out [`DefaultListModel.addElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement(E)). General advice: If you're trying to do something like this but can't quite figure out how, browse through the javadocs for the classes you are using, you might find something useful that you didn't know existed. :)

Comment: You might want to give this a read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Answer (score 2):

in your add listener, you repopulate the `ListModel` from `ListArray`, but in remove, you only remove the element from `ListModel`, not from `ListArray` that you use later.

Strictly speaking, `ListArray` is redundant. Just work with `ListModel` directly. If you can't do that, refactor repopulating the model into its own method, and call that from both listeners after manipulating `ListArray`